# android file browser preference

Tags: android, root, preferences

I have been trying to find a way to have a preference option where you can select a zip file from a file browser. How can I implement that in an app?

I also want to use the openrecoveryscript to flash that zip using TWRP recovery.

I can't seem to find any clear and definite answer.

I am also assuming my app will need root privileges to do all this. How do I implement that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.